# Error while implementing Fractional Differentiation

Tags: python

I am trying to implement Fractional Differentiation in python but i get an error.

```
def fractional_derivative(x):
    # fractiona derivative formula implementation
    x, a, b, c = smp.symbols('x a b c', real = True)
    f = smp.exp(-a*smp.sin(x**2)) * smp.sin(b**x) * smp.log(c * smp.sin(x)**2 /x) 
    dfdx = smp.diff(f,x)
    d4fdx4  = smp.diff(f,x,4).evalf()
    d4fdx4.subs([(x, 4), (a , 1), (b , 2), (c, 3)]).evalf()
    d4fdx4_f = smp.lambdify((x,a ,b,c) , d4fdx4)
    y = d4fdx4_f(x, a=1, b=2, c=3)
    print("Successfully Implemented and new feature are created based on Fractional Derivative.") 



X_train_vectorized = fractional_derivative(X_train_vectorized)
```

error is?

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Pow which has no callable sin method
```

Comment: Hi, the error is because the input value for x = 0. 0 is an invalid input because `f` contain the `(sin(x))^2`. Therefore, make sure that `X_train_vectorized` do not contain any `x=0`.

Comment: For clearly, make sure that `X_train_vectorized` do not contain any value that make `sin(x)=0`.

Comment: thank you it's helpful for me brother.